# setContentView in a fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-edittext

I tried to use setContentView in this fragment. But this is not possible.
I would like to know why? and how i can fix this problem?

my destination is to open a new view, if the login is right. I hope u understand what i mean.

```
package de.ibers.coffeelist;
        if (isValid) {
            Button buttonLogin = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText pinEdit = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.et_pin);
                    String inputPin = pinEdit.getText().toString();

                    if(inputPin.equals(_pin)) {
                           setContentView(R.layout.buyview);
                            }
                     else {
                        Log.d("buttonLogin ", "faild");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Override onCreateView method in fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buyview, container, false);
}
```